# Generating WSDL & disco files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wsdl, disco

i want to generate a wsdl and a disco file automatically (e.g. via a bat-file).

these files will be generated if a service reference is added to a (test) project.

wsdl.exe and disco.exe are missing.

can you tell me best practice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tools are installed in the Windows SDK directory.  For VS2010, the default install path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2022 you'll find the tools here: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools